# How to use variables as arguments in a Test case using NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, testcase

I'm curious if it is possible to pass local variables as **arguments** in a `TestCase` using the NUnit Framework.
Here is an example:

```
public XDocument config = XDocument.Load(Constants.configFile);

[Test(config)]
public void TestMethod(XDocument xml)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any simple solution how I can make this work?

Comment: I normally set them up as members of the test class, perhaps initializing them in a startup method

Comment: Yes that's possible. But in my case I end up with a few test methods that are very similar. That's where in my opinion a `TestCase` would do its job.

Comment: Attributes do not work like that in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, you can't do that because C# won't let you use the value of a non-constant object as the argument to an attribute.

But even if the syntax were possible, NUnit couldn't do it because...

1. The value is initialized when  the the class is constructed
2. The class is not constructed until you **run** the tests.
3. NUnit needs the test case argument **before** you run the tests.

[The last point is what allows NUnit, when used under a GUI runner to display all the tests before you run them.]

The simplest approach to this would be to make `config` a static member and use it directly from within your tests rather than as an argument. I understand from your comment that this won't work for your situation.

In that case you can solve the problem with a layer of indirection. If you switch from use of `TestCase` to `TestCaseSource`, you can use a static method as the source and have that method execute whatever code you desire in order to return the list of values to be used for test cases. For example...

```
static public IEnumerable<XDocument> Config()
{
    yield return XDocument.Load(Constants.configFile);
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(Config)]
public void TestMethod(XDocument xml)
{
    ...
}
```

The source is returning an `IEnumerable<XDocument>` rather than just an `XDocument` because `TestCaseSourceAttribute` is actually intended to return a number of test cases. We're slightly abusing it here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I just tried it out and it works fine. It's definitely a good alternative, but sad there is nothing easier that can be used.